# How do I select two sequential elements in a two dimensional array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating an automatic seat assignment web app.  I can assign a single person to a seat.  How do I assign two people sitting side by side in the same column?

```
 public bool[,] seatTwoPerson(bool[,] seatArray)
{
    for (int row = 0; row <= 29; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 5; col++)
        {
            if (!seatArray[row, col])
            {
                seatArray[row, col] = true;
                return seatArray;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What does it means sitting side by side? Same row or same column?

Comment: Same column Davide.  sorry for the confusion

Comment: @MattBurland No, he's not passing the array by reference.  The array *is* a reference.  It is being passed by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check both seats:

```
if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row+1, col])
```

Then set both to true if you find a match:

```
seatArray[row, col] = true;
seatArray[row+1, col] = true;
```

Also you need to adjust your for loop so that `row+1` doesn't go past the end:

```
for (int row = 0; row <= seatArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1; row++)
```

Comment: That is assuming that the given seat is the one "above" (for want of a better term) and the other one is below it and not the other way around.

Comment: The situation is symmetric. It does not matter which one is "above" and which one is "below" because they are both treated exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change you inner for

```
for (int col = 1; col <= 5; col++)
    {
        if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col-1])
        {
            seatArray[row, col] = true;
            seatArray[row, col-1] =true;
            return seatArray;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Don't forget to check boundary conditions.